# Which one is faster and why? 1. Array 2. Link List. If we just want to iterate in for loop and print it

Tags: c++, data-structures, computer-science

Which one is faster and why?  1. Array  2. Link List.  If we just want to iterate in for loop and print it without regard to the cpu cache.

Comment: Both are O(n) to enumerate.

Comment: Link list is built on array, so it can never be faster than array.

Comment: @Neoh not necessarily, that's an implementation detail. And it would be a rather strange linked list that was..

Comment: @Neoh That’s wrong, it’s a fundamentally different thing, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "printing it" part is going to be the same regardless of where the object is stored.

The only part that will be different is the "move to the next item".

For an array it involves incrementing a pointer -- quite possibly the fastest operation of a CPU.

For a linked-list, it involves loading a value from memory -- a really fast operation, but not was fast as incrementing.

Then there are other concerns.  An array will be contiguous, and take up less overall space than a linked list, meaning better use of the cache.

But, keep in mind - both are blindingly fast -- but, an array would be slightly faster.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is negligible. It would depend on exactly how you write the loop, and optimizations in the compiler. If you print it to the screen in a gui, that in itself will have more overhead than both put together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query is only about sequential access.

Arrays will be faster at any given time for sequential access, prime reason being newer CPU are optimized for that.

If we ignore CPU optimization even after that array access will be faster. Lets look at the steps for both operation which will help in understanding the reason.

Array access:

```
int a[10];
int *ptr = a;
```

access next element is all about doing

```
*(ptr++);
```

The operations involved are
1. Reading value of ptr
2. Increment current value by 1
3. Accessing the new address

Linked List:

```
Node {  
  int data;  
  Node* next;
};
```

accessing next data will be this

```
(*(node->next))->data;
```

1. reading value of node
2. move in address table to reach member next
3. read value of next
4. accessing the value at next

Hope this helps you in understanding why array access will be faster. also when you add CPU optimization for array 1 & 2 will be optimized even further. Having said that in real life application you will feel a negligible difference

Answer (score 0):

Array is faster than linked list. Mainly because array consecutively stores all elements. Basic linked list doesn't guarantee consequent access.

Without regard of cpu cache is quite strange assumption because mainly cache gives main performance in using array over linked list.

Linked list has pointers that connect elements to each other, while array doesn't have this overweighted structure. You iterate over array, but you don't iterate over linked list directly.

You should not compare them mathematically in terms of Big O notation, because that gives the same performance ("Devils in the details").

Answer (score 0):

Arrays will always be faster as compared to LinkedList.. Arrays store the data directly to a memory location. Linkedlist will create nodes,add data to the nodes and then store it.. Again while iterating the linkedlist will use the pointers to go to the next element and print whereas in arrays u only provide the location which will be from 0 to sizeof array...